# Custom view looks duplicated when modifying items

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this weird behavior when creating a custom view and modifying text and visibility, the view looks like it's rendered twice.

Here I'm changing the title and description text and showing the button **Ver detalles**

[image: Error showed]

This is Custom view

```
class KitChoiceItemView @JvmOverloads constructor(
context: Context,
attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
defStyle: Int = 0): ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyle) {

private var binding: KitChooiceItemViewBinding

private var isActive = false

init {
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.kit_chooice_item_view, this, true)
    binding = KitChooiceItemViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)
}

fun setupToHome() {
    binding.iconCircle.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_insc_home))
    binding.titleText.text = "Entrega a domicilio"
    binding.descriptionText.text = "Agrega una dirección para que podamos hacerte entrega de tu Kit a esa ubicación"
    binding.priceText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    binding.detailsButton.visibility = View.GONE

    binding.selectButton.setOnClickListener {
        if (isActive) {
            isActive = false
            binding.cardView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.gray_border)
        } else {
            isActive = true
            binding.cardView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.kit_item_selected)
        }
    }
}

fun setupToPlace() {
    binding.iconCircle.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_insc_location))
    binding.titleText.text = "Recoger kit en la expo"
    binding.descriptionText.text = "Al seleccionar esta opción, omite el paso de entrega a domicilio y continuas para realizar el pago."
    binding.priceText.visibility = View.GONE
    binding.detailsButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    binding.selectButton.setOnClickListener {
        if (isActive) {
            isActive = false
            binding.cardView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.gray_border)
        } else {
            isActive = true
            binding.cardView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.kit_item_selected)
        }
    }

}}
```

This is how Im implementing the custom view in my frame layout

```
<com.asdeporte.asdeportev2.ui.reusableview.inscription.KitChoiceItemView
            android:id="@+id/address_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/
<com.asdeporte.asdeportev2.ui.reusableview.inscription.KitChoiceItemView
            android:id="@+id/delivery_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>
```

Setting the custom state

```
binding.addressView.setupToHome()
binding.deliveryView.setupToPlace()
```

Comment: Why do you inflate your layout twice during `init`? Remove `R.layout` inflation if you're inflating the binding.

Comment: That's the error, it's my firs time using binding, and I was using some of the old code, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was inflating the layout twice, had to remove R.layout